# C++ multiple member function callbacks without using std::bind, std::function or boost

Tags: c++, callback, bind, pointer-to-member

I have an application which requires one or many member functions of an object to be used as callbacks when a hardware event occurs in a monitoring object. The callbacks require no arguments.

Normally I would use boost or the standard library functions (std::function, std::bind) to wrap a member function to be called but I cant use them as they (boost, C++11) are not supported or allowed on the platform. Im not sure of the efficiency either but thats off-topic.

In short, I have written class (MonitorSwi) that spawns a thread to wait for hardware events. The hardware event and callback will be configured when the object is created such that many other objects, such as DeviceManager below  can utilise this encapsulated functionality.

Apart from using bind, another method is to have a base class with a pure virtual handler implemented by the child object. However, some of the 'DeviceManagers' handle multiple SWIs which require different handlers.

The method I am currently using is to have a static member which redirects to the particular object instance and specified handler for the SWI.

I have written a simple example with all unnecessary code stripped out:

```
#include <iostream>

class MonitorSwi
{
public:
   typedef void (*SwiHandlerFunc_t)(void*);

   MonitorSwi(int id, void* pInstance, SwiHandlerFunc_t handler) :
      m_id(id),
      m_instance(pInstance),
      m_handler(handler)
   {
   }

   void HandleEvent()
   {
      std::cout << "MonitorSwi::HandleEvent() Handle SWI ID = " << m_id << std::endl;
      (*m_handler)(m_instance);
   }

private:
   int              m_id;
   void*            m_instance;
   SwiHandlerFunc_t m_handler;
};


class DeviceManager
{
public:
   DeviceManager() :
      m_Swi1(1, this, HandleSwi1), // Register handler for SWI 1 events
      m_Swi2(2, this, HandleSwi2)  // Register handler for SWI 2 events
   {
   }

   static void HandleSwi1(void* pInstance)
   {
      std::cout << "DeviceManager::HandleSwi1() Redirect to object..." << std::endl;
      DeviceManager* ptr = reinterpret_cast<DeviceManager*>(pInstance);
      ptr->HandleSwi1Member();
   }

   static void HandleSwi2(void* pInstance)
   {
      std::cout << "DeviceManager::HandleSwi2() Redirect to object..." << std::endl;
      DeviceManager* ptr = reinterpret_cast<DeviceManager*>(pInstance);
      ptr->HandleSwi2Member();
   }

   void HandleSwi1Member()
   {
      std::cout << "DeviceManager::HandleSwi1Member()" << std::endl;

      // Process event that SWI 1 has signalled...
   }

   void HandleSwi2Member()
   {
      std::cout << "DeviceManager::HandleSwi2Member()" << std::endl;

      // Process event that SWI 2 has signalled...
   }

   MonitorSwi m_Swi1;
   MonitorSwi m_Swi2;
};

int main()
{
   DeviceManager device;

   // Fake hardware calling SWI 1 (normally performed by hardware event handler)
   device.m_Swi1.HandleEvent();

   // Fake hardware calling SWI 2 (normally performed by hardware event handler)
   device.m_Swi2.HandleEvent();

   return 0;
}
```

Output from the test application:

```
MonitorSwi::HandleEvent() Handle SWI ID = 1
DeviceManager::HandleSwi1() Redirect to object...
DeviceManager::HandleSwi1Member()
MonitorSwi::HandleEvent() Handle SWI ID = 2
DeviceManager::HandleSwi2() Redirect to object...
DeviceManager::HandleSwi2Member()
```

I'm sure there must be a way using a template to specify the class type and one or many member function handlers declared in that class type.

Are there more efficient or generic ways of achieving the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply store

```
typedef void (T::*SwiHandlerFunc_t)();
```

(for a type `T` taken as a template parameter for `MonitorSwi<T>`) and call it by

```
(m_instance->*m_handler)();
```

The full code is in this [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fcf7a7063e7ba53).